# Automaticly scrolling if not done by user

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scroll, velo

Is there a possibility for a script whic scroll down to an anchor after 3sec if the user hasn't scrolled down to this anchor?

I've tried to do something with i/else statements but since I'm very new to js and wix code it's a hard time for me.
I've tried to do it around these lines of code:

```
$w.onReady( function() {
setTimeout(function (parameter) {
    $w("#anchor1").scrollTo()
  }, 2000)
});
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Raphael

Comment: First check if you see any error in your browser console? Then what is the value of the variable `$w`? Are you sure your anchor exists?

Comment: Can you try: `$( document ).ready(...)` instead?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz Thank you for the help. I'm not having an issue with ine of code. The problem I'm struggling right now is that I dont understand how to complete the code. I would like to add something with the if/else statement so that if e.g text 3 is on viewport no action should be triggert, and if not the code above should be triggered

Comment: Actually. I just checked and your code should work. maybe the anchor id is wrong?